# response json in body or thymeleaf template depend of condition

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

In my GlobalExceptionHandler I process my exceptions from validator. Usually I send json response with error but sometimes I need to send error as html page by thymeleaf pattern.

```
@ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String constraintViolation(HttpServletResponse response, final Throwable throwable) throws WebApiException {
        if (throwable.getMessage().startsWith("change")){
           return "400";
        }
        String errMsg = throwable.getMessage().replaceAll(".*\\s?:\\s?(.*)$", "$1");
        return new RestApiException(1007, errMsg).toString();
    }
```

If I use @ResponseBody everythig response as plaint text. But for condition "change", I wanna use html template "400" by thymeleaf. How to set response mode manually, with or without @Responsebody depends on condition.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `@ResponseBody` you should return `ModelAndView`. Then you can, based on your condition, choose the view. Either Thymeleaf template or [Jackson view](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-view-jackson) to serialize the model to JSON.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public String constraintViolation(HttpServletRequest request, final Throwable throwable, Model model){
        
        String errMsg = throwable.getMessage().replaceAll(".*\\s?:\\s?(.*)$", "$1");

        if (!request.getHeader("Accept").startsWith("application/json")){
            model.addAttribute("error", errMsg);
            return "400";
        }

        String error = new RestApiException(1007, errMsg).toString();
        model.addAttribute("error", error);
        return "json";
    }
```

And json pattern for thyamleaf

```
[(${error})]
```